# Request Entity Too Large in GoDaddy server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, server

I am using a server hosted by GoDaddy, But when I post data of size greater than 1MB it returns a `413 "Request Entity Too Large"` response. I cannot find the `httpd.conf` file and cannot affect the `.htaccess` changes. How can I increase the `LimitRequestBody` to 50MB.

I am using **shared hosting**.

Here's a screenshot of the response I get:

[image: Here's a screenshot of the response I get]

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Did you end up moving to a different server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having shared hosting plan with godaddy, as of right now, I just tested, maximum LimitRequestBody have to be set at 500kb. 
Seems like used to be 1MB. 
And, based on what I googled, you need to move to the dedicated server in order to modify these settings.

Comment: Indeed, the shared hosting from GoDaddy has a `LimitRequestBody` of 1MB and "they are not able to change it". I just chatted with their support staff

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem lies in your `php` configuration. There are two settings for file size limitation:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

These settings are normally found in the `php.ini` file. Since I have no experience with your kind of hosting I would not know if you can change it, but if you have access to the `php.ini` or have some other means of overriding `php`  settings you can follow [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/1697459) on how to do this.

By running [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) you can at least find out what the current settings are and see if this is causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to increase the file size limit in your PHP.ini file: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1409/increasing-user-file-upload-limits-using-php-ini-on-your-linux-server

Comment: I don't think he is asking how to increase file size limit. Seems like the issue he is having is to pass data in the post which is greater than 1MB.